# Why do we care about bijections in countability?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If I want to prove $A$ is countable, finding an injection $f:A \to \mathbb N$ should suffice.

Why then do we then care about bijections as means for proving countability at all? It seems to me we'd have less work finding the injection.

Comment: You need a bijection to show that $A$ is countably *infinite*, rather than just countable. (Strictly speaking you don't even need this, but you need Schroder-Bernstein to prove that, which is somewhat sophisticated machinery.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding a bijection is sufficient by the usual definition. Finding an injection is sufficient by a well known theorem. If you can use this theorem, you do not have to bother finding a bijection, since finding an injection might often require less technical things than actually finding a bijection.

Comment: I suppose my confusion led me to pose the wrong question - perhaps what I really should've asked is why does the definition of countably infinite even consider a bijection, intuitively there seems to be no need for it, we only need to know whether $A$ is "smaller" (or better isn't "bigger") than $\mathbb N$. If you could comment on this a bit, that would be great, either way, I will accept this answer, as it answers my question.

Comment: @DahnJahn Finite sets have injections into $\mathbb{N}$ as well. So the existence of an injection tells you that you have countability but it doesn't tell you whether the set is finite.

Comment: One should also look at the context of this definition. We define two sets to have the same cardinality if there exists a bijection. Then we define a set to be countably infinite, if it has the same cardinality as $\mathbb N$. So the definition a priori tells us to find a bijection.

For other infinite cardinalites, we could not make a definition just by requiring injectivity, since an injection $A \to \mathbb R$ with $A$ infinite leaves two or even more (depending on you believing in CH) possibilites for the cardinality of $A$.

So, to have a standard definition, we require bijectivity.